# __sleep() like method in Python

Tags: python, serialization

I was wondering if there's such a thing as the [`__sleep()` magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) (from PHP) implemented in Python.

I'm having an issue with a class, which Python says it's not JSON serializable, and I want to return a simple dictionary from a magic method inside the class, so that one of my libs can successfully call `json.dumps` on it. (I have no control of the line of code that does the serialization, as I said, it's done inside a library)

Comment: Can you monkey patch it or influence the `obj` that gets passed to `json.dumps`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Yeah, it's a custom object I created.

Comment: Will the library need to interact with your object or does it just `json.dumps` it? In the latter case, you could always convert your object into something dump-able just before you give it to the library.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable the accepted answer suggests using JSONEncoder. Maybe it will help you encode your object. You can have this JSONEncoder subclass as a member of your custom class

Comment: @Duncan that's what I ended up doing. Made a `to_dict` method on my object, and passing that as the param to the method that does the encoding, and on the other side, I'm populating a new instance of the class from the dictionary. If you'd kindly post the comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is tricky if you have no control over the call to `json.dumps()`. If you did, there are a number of ways this could be solved (most notably by implementing a [`default`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) function in a subclassed JSON encoder).

In your particular case, you are best to convert your object to a serializable form prior to passing it to the library. That way, when `json.dumps()` is called, your input can be serialized without error. This assumes that the library doesn't need to interact with your object and simply dumps it.